# Running the same apply function multiple times across a pandas groupby with different parameters passed in each time

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My question involves the most efficient way to apply the same function again and again to a pandas groupby object while changing the parameters passed in each time.

Suppose I have the following code that creates a simple dataframe and a trivial apply function:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'group': np.repeat(['A', 'B', 'C'], 3),
        'values': np.arange(2, 20, 2)
    })


def simple_function(data, value):
    new_df = data.sum() + value
    new_df['added'] = value
    return new_df
```

The simple_function sums across the df, adds value to this sum, and creates a new column that contains the value added.

I know how to use apply on an individual case:

```py
new_df_add_five = df.groupby('group').apply(simple_function, 5)

"""
Returns:
       values  added
group               
A          17      5
B          35      5
C          53      5
"""

new_df_add_six = df.groupby('group').apply(simple_function, 6)
```

But suppose I now want to combine the results of `new_df_add_five` and `new_df_add_six together`, to get something like this:

```py
"""
       values  added
group               
A          17      5
B          35      5
C          53      5
A          18      6
B          36      6
C          54      6
"""
```

Is there any way to achieve this without having to use a for loop across the params?:

```py
pd_list = []
for param in [5, 6]:
    pd_list.append(df.groupby('group').apply(simple_function, param))

combined_df = pd.concat(pd_list)
```

Comment: Why not do `def simple_function(data, *args)` and then pass in `apply(simple_function, 5,6)`?

Comment: Interesting idea -- so essentially just move the for loop from outside the groupby-apply and into the function itself? Would that meaningfully changes, given that a for loop is still being used somewhere?

Comment: It depends on whether your function can be vectorized on `[5,6]` or not. If yes, this allows you to do so.